# Java applet drawString not working

Tags: java, variables, applet

Please help, I am building a Java applet, and it wont let me display variables. See, this code works:

```
        g.drawString("wassup",50,25);
```

But this code doesn't:

```
int timerx = 10000;
g.drawString(timerx,50,25);
```

Comment: What type do you thing the first argument to `drawString` should be?

Comment: [drawString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)([String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) str, int x, int y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two [`Graphics.drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator,%20int,%20int%29) methods.  One accepts a `String` as a first argument and the other accepts an [`AttributedCharacterIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedCharacterIterator.html).  You are attempting to pass an `int` as the first argument, but there is no method that matches that signature.

If you want to print the characters `"10000"`, try the following code.

```
int timerx = 10000;
g.drawString(String.valueOf(timerx),50,25);
```

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875). (+1 BTW)

Comment: Thanks! I really apreciate it!

Comment: @NickPanagakis: remember to accept the answer if it satisfies you.